# How does SonarQube calculate its "Maintainability Rating"?

Tags: sonarqube, static-code-analysis, maintainability, sonarqube-web

I believe it uses Technical Debt, Added Technical Debt, Technical Debt Ration, and Technical Debt Ration on New Code.

Or does it just use Code Smells?

Does anyone understand how this rating is produced? It only provides a rating, not how that rating came to be.

Comment: You can check this documentation. https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions#MetricDefinitions-Reliability

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Robert, the document says it all:
Maintainability Rating (sqale_rating)
(Formerly the SQALE rating.) Rating given to your project related to the value of your Technical Debt Ratio. The default Maintainability Rating grid is:

A=0-0.05, B=0.06-0.1, C=0.11-0.20, D=0.21-0.5, E=0.51-1

The Maintainability Rating scale can be alternately stated by saying that if the outstanding remediation cost is:

- <=5% of the time that has already gone into the application, the rating is A
- between 6 to 10% the rating is a B
- between 11 to 20% the rating is a C
- between 21 to 50% the rating is a D
- anything over 50% is an E